# How to make an Audi A4 45 TFSI to upshift under around 3200 rpm in mid to full throtle

Tags: audi, shifting, a4

I have a 2023 Audi A4 45 TFSI sedan, purchased in Germany. I reported this situation to Audi AG and they replied after some time that is "normal", "state of the art technology", ...
According to the car dealer, this was successfully reproduced by himself on another car with same engine.
How to reproduce:

- Drive off to a clear road or put the car in a dyno;
- On the gear box lever, switch from D/S to manual mode;
- Select 3rd, 4th, 5th or 6th (on 2nd is hard to reproduce), depending on the speed which can be reached and the road/dyno conditions;
- While the engine is revving around 1500 rpm, press the throttle above 50% and perform an up shift operation (lever or right paddle) when the engine is making some torque;
- No gear is changed until around 3200 rpm mark is reached and the up shift (lever or right paddle) is pressed only at that point.

The down shifting operation doesn't suffer from this issue.

But I found an ugly workaround: Remove the foot from the gas pedal, press up shift and then accelerate again. The engine then makes a small up-revving sound as if it accelerated when the clutch was on the way to get fully coupled.

I drove another cars, including one which has a similar gear box but FWD only (DQ381-7F), which none of them prevented me from up shifting when I think it was correct to do so.

Is there any software change which allows me to up shift when I think it's correct? Also, is there any technical reason which justifies this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm thinking your best bet is to have the PCM tuned by a qualified tuner. They should be able to make it work for you the way you want it to. TBH with you, I'm not really sure if I understand what you are trying to explain, though.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find one in here, potentially not voiding the warranty. Basically, I cannot up shift in manual mode under certain conditions. What do you think that can be clarified?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm just dense, lol. It sounded like you were saying you were trying to downshift, but I probably just misread it.

Comment: I did not have that model, but my VAG with an auto DSG gearbox would never go fully into manual mode. **It still made decisions that over-rode my actions**. For example in auto mode it had a bad habit of uneccesarily downshifting from 2nd to 1st when on a rough surface, or when crossing a 'sleeping policeman' hump. Trying to prevent that by putting it in manual was in vain: it was even more eager to downshift to 1st gear, as if the engineers had thought: "ah, you are climbing a very steep mountain on a rough road. You, the mere driver, do not know what you are doing, but we, the engineers do."

Comment: ... not just that, but it would refuse to let me upshift back to 2nd gear until ... it had fully decided that I wasn't mountain climbing and I gave up trying. I suspect that "manual mode" is just a marketing ploy, and the best strategy was just to leave it in D - never any need for S either, except perhaps to flatter the driver. It seems the 'manual' mode allows the driver to up/down shift a bit sooner or a bit later than in 'drive' mode, to give the illusion that they have more control, but the engineering constraints are actually a bit more strict.

Comment: Interesting to read that. The above mentioned Audi and a few others I tested (VW, MB, BMW) only downshifts in manual mode when reaching 1000 rpm, both diesel and gasoline, regardless going downhill, uphill or flat.